# Dynamic PHP Code For Inputting User Info

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm working on a PHP form for inputting user information. I have these 3 important fields: First Name, Last Name, and E-mail. What I need to do is to set the E-mail automatically when the user enters the first two fields and before saving. For example when the user types 'First' in the First Name and 'Last' in the Last Name fields, the E-mail field should automatically show First.Last@example.com.

The code is already written and this is the part I'm working on:

```
echo '<TABLE ><TR><TD >'.TextInput($student['FIRST_NAME'],'students[FIRST_NAME]','<FONT color=red>'._('First').'</FONT>','size=12 class=cell_floating maxlength=50 style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;"').'</TD><TD>'.TextInput($student['MIDDLE_NAME'],'students[MIDDLE_NAME]',''._('Middle').'','class=cell_floating maxlength=50 style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;"').'</TD><TD>'.TextInput($student['LAST_NAME'],'students[LAST_NAME]','<FONT color=red>'._('Last').'</FONT>','size=12 class=cell_floating maxlength=50 style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;"').'</TD><TD>'.SelectInput($student['NAME_SUFFIX'],'students[NAME_SUFFIX]',''._('Suffix').'',array('Jr.'=>'Jr.','Sr.'=>'Sr.','II'=>'II','III'=>'III','IV'=>'IV','V'=>'V'),'','style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;"').'</TD></TR></TABLE>';

else
echo '<DIV id=student_name><div style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;" onclick=\'addHTML("<TABLE><TR><TD>'.str_replace('"','\"',TextInput($student['FIRST_NAME'],'students[FIRST_NAME]','','maxlength=50 style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;"',false)).'</TD><TD>'.str_replace('"','\"',TextInput($student['MIDDLE_NAME'],'students[MIDDLE_NAME]','','size=3 maxlength=50 style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;"',false)).'</TD><TD>'.str_replace('"','\"',TextInput($student['LAST_NAME'],'students[LAST_NAME]','','maxlength=50 style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;"',false)).'</TD><TD>'.str_replace('"','\"',SelectInput($student['NAME_SUFFIX'],'students[NAME_SUFFIX]','',array('Jr.'=>'Jr.','Sr.'=>'Sr.','II'=>'II','III'=>'III','IV'=>'IV','V'=>'V'),'','style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;"',false)).'</TD></TR></TABLE>","student_name",true);\'>'.$student['FIRST_NAME'].' '.$student['MIDDLE_NAME'].' '.$student['LAST_NAME'].' '.$student['NAME_SUFFIX'].'</div></DIV>';
echo'</td></tr>';


echo '<tr><td>'._('Email').'</td><td>:</td><td>'.TextInput($student['EMAIL'],'students[EMAIL]','','size=100 class=cell_medium maxlength=100').'</td></tr>';
```

I don't know how I'm supposed to edit it or where to add the jquery code :/
I appreciate your help, thank you :)

Comment: You don't need something as complex as ajax, unless you need to retrieve the email address from a database. Just use Javascript and the `onchange` event of the inputs.

Comment: Do you want to find username from database which matches firstname and lastname ? or Do you want to perform some string operation like concat to fill the email field?

Comment: I hope your code isn't formatted like this in your project as well... If you use proper indentation, it'll be a lot more readable and maintainable!

Comment: Actually its an open source code and I'm supposed to edit it :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
First Name : <input type="text" id="firstName" value=""><br />
Last Name : <input type="text" id="lastName" onchange="createEmail()"><br />
Email : <input type="text" id="email">
```

Javascript

```
<script>
function createEmail() {
    var fn = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
    var ln = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
    document.getElementById("email").value = fn+"."+ln+"@example.com";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much this code is clean and understandable but I'm not able to figure out how to use it. I edited my question if you can please check it. I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1):

There are no need any ajax for this.

Use the jQuery [blur](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) function to test, is the user has leaved the text input field (or use the [keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/)), and test, is the first/last name is filled. If yes, then you can get the values of the fields with `val()` function, and then you can generate the email, and set the value of the email field.

You need something like this:

```
$('#firstName', '#lastName').keyup(function() {
    var domain = 'example.com';
    var email = $('#firtName').val() + '.' + $('#lastName').val() + '@' + domain;
    $('#email').val(email);
});
```

Comment: You should also bind `.change()`

Comment: Thnx for your help. Could you please check my question after I edit it? cz I don't know how to apply your help on my code. thnx again

Comment: sorry, i can not help you, because i do not know, what the output of your TextInput function. I need to see your html code, what textinput generate. But, you should use the id or class of your textinput to get the value of them. In my example, the textinput first name has an id `firstName`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need ajax for this, take a look on the <kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/bepktgrs/2/)</kbd>

```
$('body').on('blur', '.firstname, .lastname', function(){
    var fname = $.trim($('.firstname').val()), 
        lname = $.trim($('.lastname').val()), 
        email = $('#email'), 

        // Set your domain name here
        prefix = '@example.com';

    if( fname != "" && lname != "" )
        email.val( fname + '.' + lname + prefix );
    else if( fname == "" && lname == "" )
        email.val("");
    else 
        email.val( (fname != "" ? fname : lname) + prefix );

});
```

Comment: Thank you so much this does exactly what I need, but my code is a little bit complicated I edited my question if you can please check it. thnx again